# How to resize image appropriately and set its height and width in android

Tags: android, image

I know this may strike out as a dumb question but i bet some of you had this problem before.From the screenshot,i am attempting to set an image in an activity.However my image brings up these spaces i dont know how to get rid of them.I mean is there a way,either in xml or to programmatically resize image to fit the height and width?In short,is there a way i can get rid of these spaces above and below?
[image]

My xml:

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp.Categories.Lips">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rectangle"
        android:src="@drawable/img4" />

    <TextView

        android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using scaletype tag in imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make the bitmap fill the width and height you can add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your ImageView. This way your bitmap will be scaled in x and y independently, making your bitmap fill entirely the ImageView

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done by a single line of code. Here's the trick :)

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Add this in `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rectangle"
        android:src="@drawable/img4" />
```